# laravel 8. Una ruta carga una vista en blanco (solo carga el navbar del template..)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

llevo un rato mirando un problema que tengo con una ruta y es que tengo el **admincontroller@usersList** para que cargue una vista pero la carga en blanco.

**admincontroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * Lista todos los usuarios, para tener una vista general de los usuarios actuales de la web
     */
    public function usersList(Request $request){
//        $users = User::with(['roles'])->get();
//        dd($users);
//        dd('hola');
        return view('admin.all_users');
    }
}
```

a ese controlador llega, de hecho los **dd´s** que de ven comentados si se cargan. ..

**rutas**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

    /**
     * Rutas Admins
     */
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','as'=>'admin.'],function (){
       Route::get('users_list',[AdminController::class,'usersList'])->name('usersList');
    });
});
```

**vista admin.usersList**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('background-image','storage/system/Wallpaper/Desktop/Hunt-Wallpaper-9-1920x1080.jpg')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>hola</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Que extiende de la plantilla app:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>



    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<style>
    body{
        background: url(@yield('background-image')) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
@yield('css')
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav_bar">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link {{Route::is('home') ? 'active font-weight-bold' : ''}}"
                               href="{{Route::is('home') ? '#' : route('home')}}"
                            >
                                Inicio
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @role('admin')
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown show bg-danger rounded" id="admin_menu">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                Admin
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" id="">
                                <a class="nav-link {{Route::is('admin.usersList') ? 'active font-weight-bold' : ''}}"
                                   href="{{Route::is('admin.usersList') ? '#' : route('admin.usersList')}}"
                                >
                                    Lista de usuarios
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        @endrole

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link {{ Route::is('login') ? 'active font-weight-bold' : '' }}" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link {{ Route::is('register') ? 'active font-weight-bold' : '' }}" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div id="nav_bar" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lsa otras vistas cargan bien pero no se que le pasa a esa vista. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Estas devolviendo `return view('admin.all_users')` pero tu vista de llama admin.usersList

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
 return view('admin.all_users');
```

a

```
 return view('admin.usersList');
```